# How can I print the lines of four files together?

Tags: bash, for-loop, solaris

I have four files and i want to print the 1st line of file1, file2, file3, file4 , then the second line of file1,file2,file3,file4, and then the 3rd line of each file and so on

I tried the following code but it gave me an error:

```
for i in $(cat $file1)
do 
for j in $(cat $file2)
do
for k in $(cat $file3)
do 
for l in $(cat $file4)

echo "${i}"
echo "${j}"
echo "${k}"
echo "${l}"

done
done
done
done
```

so what can i use other than echo ?

Comment: Try the `paste` command

Comment: it doesn't work it gives me I/O error is there another way

Comment: I tried using while , it gave me not a valid identifier. I want the output to be a column.

Answer (score 6):

There is s tool for that already.

```
paste "$file1" "$file2" "$file3" "$file4"
```

Use `paste -d $'\n'` if you don't want columnar output. (Thanks, @AnsgarWiechers!)

Comment: Add `-d"\n"` if you want the lines from each file in separate lines instead of the same line.

Answer (score 1):

Use `paste`.

```
paste file1 file2 file3 file4
```

Answer (score 1):

Will this do it for you?

```
paste -d '\n' file1 file2 file3 ...
```

If you want the contents the files on one line:

```
paste file1 file2 file3 ...
```